# Howto retrieve windows 2008 service stored password

Tags: windows, services, windows-domain

We have Windows 2008 R2 joined on domain.
There is an customized application/service installed in this system by a 3rd party vendor.
Is there any way i can see the service stored password?

Comment: If you have the right to the password, why not contact the vendor?

Comment: the vendor is not in contact now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after inspection, I found out that the service was configured to use the local pc account, and since the servers was jointed to domain and dueto domain policies local account was not allowed to start the service and thus it was giving logon failure message when we login via other account to the server.

Solution was to add the local pc account which starts the service in the domain policy so that it can start the service.

thank you.